# What Heroes spawn during each wave for Junkenstein's Revenge Endless Mode?

Tags: overwatch

I was trying out the new Gamemode for the Halloween event in Overwatch and trying to plan out the best strategy for getting the different event achievements this year.

**I was wondering, what spawns during each of the 12 waves and each Bonus Wave in Junkenstein's Revenge Endless Mode?**

I am just looking for when and which the enemy Heroes spawn, as well as Rip-Tires. I am not really concerned about the Zomnic spawns.

Comment: Not really an answer, but so far I've seen Junkrat, Symmetra, Mercy, Reaper, and Roadhog appear at various points during the game. Who spawns when may or may not be dependent on the mode though. Reaper tends to come first, then Roadhog, then Symmetra, Junkrat, and finally Mercy, but some respawn later on.

Comment: From my experience playing last night it seems to be Junk tire, Junk Tire, Reaper, Roadhog, Sym, Reaper, Junk & Roadhog, and then Junk & Roadhog & Mercy, but after that it gets really hectic with multiple spawns of the same hero. It feels like it is the same each time but I'm not entirely sure. Also this is on Normal Difficulty so I don't know if there are difference between difficulties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spawns are as follows:

- Wave 1: Reaper x1
- Wave 2: Shock Tire x3
- Wave 3: Shock Tire x1, Junkenstein's Monster x1
- Wave 4: Shock Tire x1, Junkenstein x1
- Wave 5: Shock Tire x1, Reaper x2
- Wave 6: Shock Tire x3, Summoner x1
- Wave 7: Junkenstein's Monster x2
- Wave 8: Junkenstein's Monster x1, Junkenstein x1, Witch x1
- Wave 9: Shock Tire x1, Reaper x3
- Wave 10: Shock Tire x3, Summoner x2
- Wave 11: Shock Tire x1, Junkenstein's Monster x2
- Wave 12: Shock Tire x2, Junkenstein's Monster x1, Junkenstein x1, Witch x1
- Bonus Wave 1: Shock Tire x2, Reaper x3
- Bonus Wave 2: Shock Tire x5, Summoner x2
- Bonus Wave 3: Junkenstein's Monster x3
- Bonus Wave 4: Shock Tire x1, Junkenstein's Monster x1, Junkenstein x1, Witch x2
- Bonus Wave 5: Shock Tire x2, Reaper x4
- Bonus Wave 6: Shock Tire x5, Summoner x3
- Bonus Wave 7: Shock Tire x1, Junkenstein's Monster x3
- Bonus Wave 8: Shock Tire x1, Junkenstein's Monster x1, Junkenstein x2, Witch x2
- Bonus Wave 9: Shock Tire x3, Reaper x4
- Bonus Wave 10: Shock Tire x6, Summoner x3
- Bonus Wave 11: Junkenstein's Monster x4
- Bonus Wave 12: Shock Tire x1, Junkenstein's Monster x2, Junkenstein x2, Witch x2
- Bonus Wave 13: Shock Tire x3, Reaper x5
- Bonus Wave 14: Shock Tire x5, Summoner x4
- Bonus Wave 15: Shock Tire x1, Junkenstein's Monster x4
- Final Wave: Junkenstein's Monster x2, Junkenstein x2, Summoner x2, Witch x2

[Thanks to this post.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/75pkj9/junkenstien_legendary_endless_specs/)

Comment: Ahh Excellent, Redditors with too-much time on their hands never fail to please. Only other thing that I could think is actual times that they spawn (which is useful for planning ults), I might give this persons method a try when I get home to get the rest of the info. Too bad Arqade doesn't support tables though, as the bullet ed list is kind of hard to read and codeblocks are bad for this sort of info.

Comment: I couldn't think of any way to make this look pretty, feel free to change the style.

Comment: I will give a think, but it is Arqades fault not yours. Not a lot of tools to work with for tabled data like this. They have `&nbsp` but not tabs or inline indenting has far as I can tell.

Comment: I think (but am not 100% certain) that waves are time-based, not enemy based. So for example, if you don't kill all 4 Reapers in bonus wave 5 by the time the countdown runs out, you'll have finish killing them AND the 3 Summoners that spawn next.